# How to list taxonomy terms grouped by a field with Views

Tags: 7, views

I have a taxonomy vocabulary called 'clients'. There's a field on that called 'category' which is a simple text list.

I want a view that results in something like:

> ### Category Foo
>
> (rendered term in category Foo)
>
> (rendered term in category Foo)
>
> ### Bar Category
>
> (rendered term in Bar category)

It seems I can group by a field, but only if I select fields as the output. Is there a way to have it **group by field** (for the headings) but use the **rendered terms** (with a particular view mode) within the grouping?

Answer (score 0):

A-ha!

Tick the "Force using fields" option under the page style. This turns on the fields bit which you can then use to group by.

[image: screenshot]